# Internet Explorer: Erroneous CSS string from inline-style attribute

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I can get the content of a style attribute like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('id').getAttribute('style'));
```

For an element `<div id="id" style="display: none;"></div>`, this would obviously return `display: none;`.

However, if the string in the attribute fails to render to valid css, it will not get returned, for example:

```
<div id="id" style="display: none; border: some random nonsense"></div>
```

would still return only `display: none;`.

I have also tried to access `document.getElementById('id').style.cssText` with the same result.

Is there a way to access the inline style attribute even if it doesn't evaluate to valid css rules?

**Edit** it seems that only Internet Explorer is producing the described result, so I added the relevant tags.

Comment: `document.getElementById('id')`

Comment: Interesting. I would have expected `getAttribute` to always return the raw value of the attribute, whether it is valid or not.

Comment: What's the use case here? I can't think of any good reason that would require using invalid CSS in the inline style.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/shr8290L/. Console shows `display: none; border: some random nonsense`

Comment: @j08691 what browser are you using? I'm so used to Firefox I forget about the others :)

Comment: @Pointy - Chrome, but I get the same result in FF

Comment: @JoeAttardi trying to preprocess the nodes but they're already parsed to DOM elements before I can do anything.

Comment: I can reproduce it only if something tries to set another style (in Firefox). https://jsfiddle.net/shr8290L/1/

Comment: @j08691 wow you're right. I could *swear* I spent an afternoon a few years ago dealing with this, but I've got about 6 working neurons at this point so

Comment: "it seems that only Internet Explorer is producing the described result". Haha, Internet Exploder!

Comment: In IE, the element's outerHTML returns `<div id="id" style="display: none;"></div>`.  So IE must silently discard invalid inline CSS, which would make this impossible.

Comment: @RickHitchcock if I inspect the element through the F12 tools, I can still see the faulty css in the rules, so it isn't *completely gone* per se...